# Find mail JobId with specific Campaign Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Is it possible in Queries to find alle users who have opened an email with the Campaign Code of "Newsletter"... I Cant find the Campaigncode anywhere in the _dataview tables.. the closest is EmailName.. but this is an ongoing task with new email added all the time, so it need to be dynamic to include new emails...